# VBA : Insert multiple table in documnet

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a little problem with VBA for Microsoft Word. I want to add multiple table in a document file. The first one work ok. When i try to add the second it says that the tabel with index 2 doesn't exit.
Could you give me some help?
Thanks

Here is my code :

```
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oRng As Range


Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oRng = oDoc.Range(0, 0)




'Tabel 1
oDoc.Tables.Add Range:=oRng, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=2


oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Range.AutoFormat
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Range.Paragraphs.SpaceBefore = 12
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Range.Paragraphs.SpaceAfter = 0
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Range.Font.Size = 11
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Code"
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Issue"
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Date"
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "GEURIW-PM1-TN-02"
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "0.1"
oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = "20/12/2015"
oDoc.Paragraphs.Add

Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
oDoc.Tables.Add Range:=Range(0.1, 0.1), NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertBefore "GNSS ENVIRONMENT AND USER    REQUIREMENTS CHARACTERISATION ON THE DANUBE RIVER"
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Bold = True
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Size = 18
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS"
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Format.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).SpaceBefore = 10
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf + "GEURIW"
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(2).Format.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Font.Size = 26
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(2).SpaceBefore = 10
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf + "DATA PROCESSING METHODOLOGY"
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(3).Format.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(3).Range.Font.Size = 18
oDoc.Tables.Item(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paragraphs(3).SpaceBefore = 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code is probably inside the first cell of the first table:

```
Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
```

All table cells have at least one paragraph, and they are part of ActiveDocument.Paragraphs. I'm assuming from your problem description that's not what you intend - that you want the tables one after the other. In that case:

```
oDoc.Paragraphs.Add
Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
```

To target the last paragraph in the document. You also want to be careful that there are TWO paragraph marks following the first table (if this is a relatively recent version of Word there should be when you add one paragraph, in very early versions there might not be). If the second table were to be inserted in the paragraph immediately following the first table, the two tables would "merge" into one table, automatically.