# How to separate records attached to the same bookmark in different tables?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a table in word that I'm populating via vba in msaccess. My code runs, however, the subsequent records follow after each other in the same table. Instead, I want a new table for each function or rather follow up the same function in the same cell.

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set wApp = Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mas_sywee\Documents\BCP_Part2_bk.docx")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mailmerge2")

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    DoEvents
        wDoc.Bookmarks("fname").Range.Text = Nz(rs!FName, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("preact").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PreActivity, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("preteam").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PA_Team, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("rto").Range.Text = Nz(rs!ServiceRTO, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("rtoact").Range.Text = Nz(rs!RTOActivity, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("rtoteam").Range.Text = Nz(rs!RTO_Team, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("postrto").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PostRTO, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("postact").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PostActivity, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("postteam").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Post_Team, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("dd").Range.Text = Nz(rs!DD_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("ddpro").Range.Text = Nz(rs!DDProcess_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("sd").Range.Text = Nz(rs!SD_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("sdpro").Range.Text = Nz(rs!SDProcess_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itpreact").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PreActivity_IT, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itpreteam").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PATeam_IT, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itrto").Range.Text = Nz(rs!ServiceRTO, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itrtoact").Range.Text = Nz(rs!RTOActivity_IT, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itrtoteam").Range.Text = Nz(rs!RTOTeam_IT, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itpost").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PostRTO, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itpostact").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PostActivity_IT, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itpostteam").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PostTeam_IT, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itdd").Range.Text = Nz(rs!DD_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itddpro").Range.Text = Nz(rs!DDProcess_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itsd").Range.Text = Nz(rs!SD_merged, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("itsdpro").Range.Text = Nz(rs!SDProcess_merged, "")
        
 _
rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set doc = Nothing
Set wDoc = Nothing
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Currently, the table looks like this:

| Function |
| --- |
| FName1FName2 |

But instead I want an output where each Fname has its own table. Is it possible?

Comment: Possibly can't use bookmarks. See if these help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-add-multiple-tables-to-a-word-document/ and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78824b79-4fd4-4b01-b78d-661a5e0397d5/creating-multiple-tables-in-a-word-2007-doc-from-access-2007-using-vba?forum=accessdev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create table in Word Document From Access using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006698/create-table-in-word-document-from-access-using-vba)

Comment: @June7 ya bookmarks didn't work, I instead used a recordset to fill in the cells in a template. However, currently, I can only get it to delete the non-populated tables. Trying to find a way to automate the replication of the tables if there are additional records.

Comment: Why have multiple tables?

Comment: @June7 the issue is that, for each function record available, there will be a table generated for that function. Ideally, for each function available in the recordset, I want to create a table that I had previously formatted in my word template. The easiest way I found was to copy and paste numerous tables and create a loop for the records to loop through n populate each table. This is as I haven't found a solution to generate a new table for each record.

Comment: Are you saying a table with a single record? Should probably start a new question with your attempted code, example data, example result.

Comment: I found a clue to adding multiple tables in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794656/vba-insert-multiple-table-in-documnet. In place of `ActiveDocument` use your wdoc variable.

Answer (score 0):

well, it might be easier to JUST add ONE column to one table, and that column can group or distinguish the data for each group of data.

I mean, this is kind of like creating invoices. You NEVER want to say create tables 1-12 for each month of the year.  So, you add ONE date column to the table, and now you do not need 12 tables anymore, do you? You can have ANY month of invoices, including last years 6th month and this years 6th month.

However, nothing is stopping you from passing a recordset to that function you posted. So, don't create (load) the reocrdset "rs" in that function, but simple create that recordset BEFORE you call that routine, and then pass that rs to the above routine you have.